# Get all Input Control ID without selectors from html page?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get an input control's ID from html page, but without using form control and selectors. If

its  possible to get any other way?

anybody help me?

```
<div><input class="textbox-default w-100-per" id="txt1" type="text" ></div>

<div><input class="textbox-default w-100-per" id="txt2" type="text" ></div>
```

i want to get  textbox id from html page

Comment: show html and code you tried

Comment: We can't read your harddisk or mind. Show us some code.

Comment: form control using to post method to get all input controls like that.but here i dont use form control

Comment: I don't think without using any selector we can get any information about it. To read input id, you need at least tag type i.e. `input` or `class` value to get the element object and then read its attribute.

Comment: without selectors how you are expecting you will get??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery code will loop through all the inputs on your page and extract their ID's

```
$("input").each(function(i,v){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Without more information, this is the best I could do.

Comment: I think OP said 'without using form control and selectors' and `$("input")` is a jQuery tag name selector. I think there is little confusion

Comment: `input` is a required selector, so OP can't get around having this available to them, long as their using jQuery, should accomplish what they need.

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr' obtained

Comment: @CSK Did you do `$(this).attr("id");` ?

Answer (score 1):

With the information you have given , i think this will help you

```
$("input").each(function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```